# Exception when log4j is moved to src and log4j does not bundled in that jar

Tags: java, log4j

log4j:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=${fileName}
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I have this in my main method when I run my application : `PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");`.

Issues:

1. I kept my log4j.properties file at the root of the project and tried to export my project as a runnable jar and when I extract the contents of it or re-import it again, I actually don't see log4j.properties in it. What should be done for the log4j to be bundled with the jar?
2. I placed the log4j file under src folder. But when I run my app, I get the below exception. What should be changed in order for log4j to work even when the log4j file is moved?

This is the exception I get:

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:290)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:194)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:164)
```

Answer (score 0):

log4j.properties should ideally not be part of the jar file itself. It is the client's (or the user of the API) responsibility to supply one.

To answer the second part of your question, try replacing ${filename} with a path like C:\mylogs.log

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding! I got it working! We don't need to provide log4j separately instead we can have it coded in our class to create a Logger and and Appender. For the second part, I don't think that is the answer. Replacing ${filename} does not matter where you place the log4j